# Blocked loading mixed active content for geobytes

Tags: html, ajax, https

I have a simple Grails application where I use [geobytes](http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?q=new) to autofill an input field in a form. Locally I was able to test it. My application has SSL certificate. And this url does not work with https, is there a way for me to bypass this mixed active content issue?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to have a [VIP Account](http://geobytes.com/vip-access/). Not sure if there are any workarounds.

Comment: I'm looking for a workaround other than getting a VIP account.